# Sequelize duplicates createdAt and updatedAt when using custom names?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following pattern in my models:

```
...
created_at: { 
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'created_at'
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'updated_at'
        }
    },
        {
            created_at: 'created_at',
            updated_at: 'updated_at',
            underscored: true,
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    );
```

To my understanding this should create "created_at" and "updated_at" columns on the model table. That is correct. Works. On table side things look good.

Problem is when I query a record. The model comes back with the "updated_at" and "created_at" fields, but it also sticks in there the "createAt" and "updatedAt" fields.

When I console the record I get back I see this:

```
... ,"created_at":"2020-04-20T17:25:38.583Z","updated_at":"2020-04-20T17:25:38.583Z","createdAt":"2020-04-20T17:25:38.583Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-20T17:25:38.583Z", ...
```

I do not want to get the NOT underscored versions of the dates when I query. Any idea what is wrong here?

I also tried:

```
...
createdAt: { 
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'created_at'
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'updated_at'
        }
    },
        {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            underscored: true,
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    );
```

But it still returns dates twice:

```
..."created_at":"2020-04-20T19:50:28.071Z","updated_at":"2020-04-20T19:50:28.071Z","createdAt":"2020-04-20T19:50:28.071Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-20T19:50:28.071Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Name a model props in the snake case:

```
    created_at: {
      field: 'created_at',
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },

    updated_at: {
      field: 'updated_at',
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
```

Correct a model options like this:

```
{
      freezeTableName: true,
      underscored: true,
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at'
}
```

Comment: I am able to name the model fields without using snakeCase, which is what I am doing. The only fields that don't work are the createdAt and updatedAt, meaning, I can rename them, but the normal "createdAt" and "updatedAt" come back anyway. I need to find a way to get rid of the snakeCase updatedAt and createdAt....

Comment: Did you pay attention to options? You wrote them as created_at and updated_at but their names are createdAt, updatedAt.That's why these options didn't work

Comment: I tried that. I edited the question to reflect that test too. I still have the same issue. I do not want to see createAt or updatedAt in my code. Only the underscore versions. Table is fine, meaning it still only shows "created_at" and "updated_at", which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The option is

```
timestamps: false,
```